# Visual Studio 2010 not showing my intellisense documentation

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, intellisense

Today I decided it was a good idea to start documenting my functions with the intellisense thing.

The problem is, when I type /// and press enter it doesn't create the tags to fill in (shouldn't it?).

And worse, even if I document my function manually:

```
/// <summary>
/// Gets something.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="somethingElse"> Something else.</param>
/// <returns> Something. </returns>
int getSomething(int somethingElse);
```

When I go and write "object.getSomething(" it only shows me the parameter, like if the documentation never existed.

Yes, I set it to generate XML documentation files in project options -> configuration properties -> c/c++ -> output and tried to rebuild the project.

No effect.

Any ideas?